# Android: Voice Recognition Stop Explicitly?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I know you can increase the amount of time to consider input complete by calling :

```
intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS,5000);
```

However, is there a way after kicking off the Android Voice recognition activity, to stop it *explicitly*, say after receiving a "keyword".

Comment: I found onStopListening(RecognitionService.Callback listener)   Here:                  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionService.html#onStopListening(android.speech.RecognitionService.Callback)                                     but I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for.....

Comment: Also what I may try (if no real solution is found) is to increase the amount of time the Voice Recognition waits for the utterance to complete then parse the results and if the keyword to signify the user is done is not found, then restart the voice recognition intent...hacky yes but may be a work around..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mike is right.

This works:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, new Long(2000));
```

You have specify a Long.  Just putting a number ("2000") gets interpreted as an Integer, which is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using the [SpeechRecognizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) class with a custom UI instead of the [RecognizerIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html) intent. [SpeechRecognizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) class has the [stopListening()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html#stopListening()) method you can call explicitly once the user presses a "stop" button.

Another way to try is to request partial results with [EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS) and search for your "stop keyword" in [RecognitionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html)'s [onPartialResults](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html#onPartialResults(android.os.Bundle)) callback, then [stopListening()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html#stopListening()) when one is detected.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! =)

You can use `.stopListening()` on the `SpeechRecognizer object`.

```
SpeechRecognizer hear = NULL;

//set up the recognizer and intent

hear.stopListening();
```

I put it in a Runable so I could control how long before it ended the speech input, and I removed the callback of that Runnable if the speech input ended so it would not try to stop a speech input that already stopped (or do collateral damage and end a speech input called after)